# Pointer to Pointer to Structure (Priority Queue)

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, struct

I'm a beginner (in C++, I'm coming from C (6 months experience)) and I'm trying to create a priority queue, but something is not working.
When I start the program and compile it, there are no errors. But there is nothing printed on the screen and the program crashes.

So here is the code:

PriorityQueue.h

```
using namespace std;

class PriorityQueue{
    private:
    struct pqentry_t{
        string value;
        float priority;
    };
    pqentry_t **_pqentry;
    int _size;
    int _next;

    public:
    PriorityQueue();
    ~PriorityQueue();
    void insert(string value, float priority);
    void printQueue();
};
```

PriorityQueue.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

#define SIZE 8
using namespace std;

PriorityQueue::PriorityQueue(){
    _size = SIZE;
    _next = 0;
    _pqentry = new pqentry_t*[_size];
}

PriorityQueue::~PriorityQueue(){
    delete[] _pqentry;
}

void PriorityQueue::insert(string value, float priority){
    _pqentry[_next]->value = value;    // this is probably not working
    _pqentry[_next]->priority = priority;
    _next++;
}

void PriorityQueue::printQueue(){
    for (int i = 0; i < _next; i++){
            cout << "Value: " << _pqentry[i]->value << endl
                 << "Priority: " << _pqentry[i]->priority << endl;
        }
        cout << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "PriorityQueue.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    PriorityQueue pq;
    pq.insert("Banana", 23);
    pq.printQueue();
}
```

I think, I know where the error is, in the PriorityQueue.cpp, here:

```
_pqentry[_next]->value = value;
_pqentry[_next]->priority = priority;
```

But I don't know what's wrong and I can't fix it. The compiler says there are no errors.

I hope, you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did allocate the _pqentry member but you need to allocate each entry of this array as well, for example:

_pqentry[_next] = new pqentry_t;

before writing to it.
And do not forget to delete those :)

Comment: You might consider just doing a single level of pointers for _pentry:
pqentry_t *_pqentry;

or, if you can, use a stl container to do the job!

Comment: Omg, I am stupid, lol. Thank you very much. Now, it works!

Yeah, I know, with one pointer it's easier and it makes more sense, but that's an homework assignment for my CS course and we have to do it with two pointers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are creating an array of pointers to pqentry_t in your constructor, but your insert method is expecting it to be an array of _pqentry structures themselves. You are not allocating space for the pqentry_t elements themselves and so when you try to dereference them in your insert method, the program crashes.

Try changing the definition of _pqentry in the class to pqentry_t *_pqentry and the allocation in the constructor to new pqentry_t[size]. This will allow your insert and printQueue methods to access the entries of _pqentry as they are written.